# Creating a shared vector with block size?

Tags: c, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I need to create a shared vector, with the same size as the block.

```
__global__ func()
{   
    const int size = blockDim.x;
    __shared__ float* Vec[size];
..
}
```

I get this error

```
error : expression must have a constant value
```

I cannot understand where the problem is, since `blockDim.x` is "constant" for each block of threads?

Comment: The way you write *constant* in quotes tells me you are not actually using a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it

```
__shared__ float Vec[size];
```

remove the star (`*`)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the section about `__shared__` of the [CUDA C++ Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared), there's some text on how to specify a size for an `extern` declared shared array.  Although it's a bit more complicated, this is the syntax on how to specify execution-time sized shared arrays.  The way you're doing it won't work.

Comment: Just to supplement this, what you will do is configure the amount of shared memory at kernel launch, just as you configure the #blocks and threads per block. eg `func <<< nBlocks, nBlockSize, nBlockSize*sizeof(float) >>> ( )`. Then Vec is declared in the kernel as `__shared__ float* Vec;` and you go from there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CUDA does not support variable length arrays (which is what you're trying to do here, regardless of the presence of the keyword `const`).

Comment: I agree with you. However because Cuda is a parallel language, it'd be quite logical to be able to create a shared vector by the threads of the same block, ... sized as the block

Comment: you can essentially use variable length arrays if you configure the shared memory size at kernel launch from the host code...

Answer (score -1):

You have to have a compiler that supports [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) to use [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).  It would seem your compiler doesn't support VLAs, so you have to have an [integer constant expression](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/constant-expressions/) for your array size.